# Is there a Palmer Drought Severity Index package in R?

Tags: r-package

Is there an active package to calculate Palmer Drought Severity Index (PDSI)in R?

scPDSI has been archived in 2021 and I'm looking for a replacement option to help determine drought index. This is the link referring to the faith of scPDSI:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/scPDSI/index.html

Thanks!

Comment: The pdsi and scPDSI packages in R produces some bad results like -99 value. So I suspect their use. Have you found any replacement. particularly scPSDI?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me on this. I haven't found a replacement. I resorted to running my analysis using PDSI data from NOAA.